# Creating new features from common part of other features in same layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, overlapping-features

[image: Problem]

I have many overlapping features in one layer and I want to get common parts of it (like in intersection function, when using two different layers). Moreover I want to sum one of features' attributes and assign it to common parts. Like in the above picture.

Is there any way to do it easy and/or quickly?

Comment: Looks like a Union.

Comment: Not quite, I can't do union on sigle layer...

Comment: I was not aware of that difference between Union in QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

1. Intersect the layer with itself.
2. Use the `join attributes by location (summary)` tool to sum the attributes of identical features. (You can find it in the Processing Toolbox. Note that this is a different tool from `join attributes by location`.)
3. Run `Delete duplicate geometries`

Answer (score 1):

from now on, you can do a union on a single layer.  Read this: [QGIS User Manual: Processing Algorithms: Vector Overlay](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union)

[image]